# how to add value to my matrix type, like an array?

Tags: c#, exception, generics, matrix, custom-data-type

I made a generic matrix type, and I want to use it like a two dimensional array, but the setter method always throws exception. How can I solve it?

Here's the code of the type:

```
class Matrix<T> where T : IComparable, IComparable<T>, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable
    {
        #region typedef
        private List<List<T>> matrix;
        #endregion
        #region overloading
        public T this[int row, int col]
        {
            get { return matrix[row][col]; }
            set { matrix[row][col] = value; }//ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        }
        #endregion
        #region functions
        public Matrix(int size)
        {
            matrix = new List<List<T>>(size);
            for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
                matrix.Add(new List<T>(size));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

And where I put the comment, there is the error.

If it helps, here's the the Main function:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Matrix<int> m = new Matrix<int>(10);
            m[0, 0] = 10;
            Console.WriteLine(m[0,0]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[List(int capacity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not add items to array:

> Initializes a new instance of the List class that is empty and has the specified initial capacity.

You want to add elements into your inner array. One option is to fill with result of `Enumerable.Repeat`:

```
     matrix.Add(new List<T>(Enumerable.Repeat(default(T), size)));
```